# Check internet connection is not working

Tags: java, android, performance

I am using the following method for checking internet connectivity but it is crashing..

```
public static boolean CheckInternetConnection() {

    ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) PropertyApplication
            .getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connec
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connec
            .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if (wifi != null && wifi.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else if (mobile != null && mobile.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Also i have added uses permission in manifest file. Here is my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

here is my logcat

```
02-23 09:43:37.549: D/dalvikvm(1896): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 36K, 8% free 2867K/3108K, paused 7ms, total 8ms
02-23 09:43:37.573: I/dalvikvm-heap(1896): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.909MB for 960012-byte allocation
02-23 09:43:37.673: D/dalvikvm(1896): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 7% free 3802K/4048K, paused 49ms, total 49ms
02-23 09:43:37.729: D/main(1896): inside main
02-23 09:43:37.837: D/libEGL(1896): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
02-23 09:43:37.849: D/(1896): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb93084a8, tid 1896
02-23 09:43:37.877: D/libEGL(1896): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
02-23 09:43:37.901: D/libEGL(1896): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
02-23 09:43:37.997: W/EGL_genymotion(1896): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-23 09:43:37.997: E/OpenGLRenderer(1896): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-23 09:43:38.017: E/OpenGLRenderer(1896): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
02-23 09:43:38.017: D/OpenGLRenderer(1896): Enabling debug mode 0
02-23 09:43:39.745: D/main(1896): inside finally
02-23 09:43:40.045: D/dalvikvm(1896): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 248K, 11% free 3750K/4200K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
02-23 09:43:40.069: I/dalvikvm-heap(1896): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.931MB for 1127532-byte allocation
02-23 09:43:40.097: D/dalvikvm(1896): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 9% free 4850K/5304K, paused 23ms, total 23ms
02-23 09:43:40.257: W/EGL_genymotion(1896): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-23 09:43:42.513: W/EGL_genymotion(1896): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-23 09:43:49.373: D/dalvikvm(1896): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 243K, 8% free 5201K/5644K, paused 54ms, total 65ms
02-23 09:43:49.577: I/dalvikvm-heap(1896): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.237MB for 1011060-byte allocation
02-23 09:43:49.653: D/dalvikvm(1896): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 987K, 22% free 5200K/6632K, paused 71ms, total 71ms
02-23 09:43:50.077: D/dalvikvm(1896): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 22% free 5189K/6632K, paused 74ms, total 77ms
02-23 09:43:50.709: I/dalvikvm-heap(1896): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.118MB for 4044204-byte allocation
02-23 09:43:50.789: D/dalvikvm(1896): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 14% free 9138K/10584K, paused 78ms, total 78ms
02-23 09:43:51.089: D/main(1896): inside prop home onCreate
02-23 09:43:51.129: I/Choreographer(1896): Skipped 148 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-23 09:43:51.285: W/EGL_genymotion(1896): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-23 09:43:53.609: D/main(1896): inside prop home intent
02-23 09:43:53.989: D/main(1896): inside prop home starting intent
02-23 09:43:54.101: D/main(1896): inside prop list onCreate
02-23 09:43:54.101: D/main(1896): inside prop list try block
02-23 09:43:54.109: D/main(1896): inside prop list try blocktrue
02-23 09:43:54.117: W/System.err(1896): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 09:43:54.121: W/System.err(1896):     at com.propvis.utils.PropertyUtil.CheckInternetConnection(PropertyUtil.java:61)
02-23 09:43:54.137: W/System.err(1896):     at com.propvis.activity.PropertyListActivity.onCreate(PropertyListActivity.java:41)
02-23 09:43:54.149: W/System.err(1896):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
02-23 09:43:54.149: W/System.err(1896):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-23 09:43:54.165: W/System.err(1896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
02-23 09:43:54.165: W/System.err(1896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-23 09:43:54.169: W/System.err(1896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-23 09:43:54.185: W/System.err(1896):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-23 09:43:54.189: W/System.err(1896):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-23 09:43:54.201: W/System.err(1896):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-23 09:43:54.205: W/System.err(1896):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-23 09:43:54.217: W/System.err(1896):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 09:43:54.217: W/System.err(1896):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-23 09:43:54.241: W/System.err(1896):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-23 09:43:54.245: W/System.err(1896):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-23 09:43:54.253: W/System.err(1896):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 09:43:54.421: W/EGL_genymotion(1896): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

Comment: Sorry but, how can it not return a value? It either returns true, false, or it crashes???

Comment: i guess it is crashing..

Comment: Crashing with what exception?

Comment: indicate line 61 on `PropertyUtil` class

Comment: .getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); it is 61th line

Comment: `getContext()` is null, for solving this just pass context to this method

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use, I hope it works for you too.

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would simply be opening a `Socket` against Google. I use the following code on many of my projects when I need to test connectivity and it definitely works.

```
Socket socket;
final String host = "www.google.com";
final int port = 80;
final int timeout = 30000;   // 30 seconds

try {
  socket = new Socket();
  socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), timeout);
}
catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
  Log.e("Sock", "I couldn't resolve the host you've provided!");
}
catch (SocketTimeoutException ste) {
  Log.e("Sock", "After a reasonable amount of time, I'm not able to connect, probably I don't have connectivity!");
}
catch (IOException ioe) {
  Log.e("Sock", "Hmmm... Sudden disconnection, probably you should retry!");
}
```

This might be tricky, though. Precisely on `UnknownHostException`s, it may take longer to timeout, about 45 seconds to timeout - but on the other side, this usually happens when **you** cannot resolve the host, so that would morelike mean that your internet access has missconfigured DNS resolution (which is not probable), or your connection is down (which is more probable).

Anyway, if you want to hedge your bets, you could solve this by two ways:

- Don't use a host, use an IP address instead. You may get several Google's IPs just using `ping` several times on the host. For instance:

  ```
  shut-up@i-kill-you ~/services $ ping www.google.com
  PING www.google.com (173.194.40.179) 56(84) bytes of data.
  ```
- Another workaround would be starting a `WatchDog` thread and finish the connection attempt after the required time. Evidently, forcely finishing would mean no success, so in your case, Google would be down.

Answer (score 0):

To give you your sample in a working version:

```
public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context Context) {

    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }

    }
    return false;
}
```